# Hibernate filters don't work on inner joins?

Tags: hibernate

I've a class `Employee` which has a filter defined on. 
The filter filters all employees with a salary less than 1000.

I also have an `EmployeePhoneNumber` class. An employee may have many `EmployeePhoneNumber`s but each `EmployeePhoneNumber` is connected to a single employee. (many-to-one)

When I enable the filter and query for employees:

`SELECT employee from Employee employee`.

The filter works fine, and only appropriate employees with a salary more than 1000 are returned.

When I query for the inner-join between employee and employees:

`SELECT employeePhoneNumber.id, employee.id from EmployeePhoneNumber employeePhoneNumber inner join employeePhoneNumber.employee employee`

The filter doesn't work, and I get phone numbers from employees with a salary less than 1000.

How can I solve it (still using filters and joins)? I know I can do this adding a subslect to my query (checking that employee is in Employees will add the necassary filter), but it's less efficient.

Comment: What happens if you reformulate your query to target the `Employee`table like this:

`from employee as e left join EmployeePhoneNumber as pn`?

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to create a similar filter in employeePhoneNumber like this:

```
<filter 
    name="salaryFilter" 
    condition="((select e.salary from Employee e where e.id = employeeId) < salaryParameter)" 
/>
```